# How can add a static html page without any control in MVC web application

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I want to add a static HTML page in  MVC (entity framework) Web application  without any model and control associated with it.
That html page i want to browse from the browser.

Thank you

Comment: Which MVC framework is the rest using?
ANd what have you tried so far?

Comment: framework 5.0.i just create html file and  kept in shared folder.and  try to run from browser .

Comment: You just add it and that's it. Theres no magic settings. If you added it to the shared folder, it would be http://localhost/views/shared/page.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just add a route of your html page .

Comment: means .can  you explain me  plz

Comment: route means the path just like   localhost/myproject/myfile.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not an obligation to have a controller for a static view. Just create a simple HTML page and use classic links to have access to this page. 
According to the framework that is used you can too use MVC routing.

Comment: it is not link to any page.it is an independent page  i just view that in browser using the file name  of that html